# Mariadb Triggers after multiple insert, update one table one one time

Tags: mariadb, trigger, update, insert, entity

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_composers_insert AFTER INSERT ON composers
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE listings SET composer_name = NEW.composer_name
WHERE composer_id = NEW.composer_id;

CREATE TRIGGER after_albums_insert AFTER INSERT ON albums FOR EACH ROW UPDATE listings SET album_name = NEW.album_name WHERE album_id = NEW.album_id;

CREATE TRIGGER after_pieces_insert AFTER INSERT ON pieces FOR EACH ROW UPDATE listings SET piece_name = NEW.piece_name WHERE piece_id = NEW.piece_id;
```

Hello I'm trying to optimize all three triggers, in a single pass.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: They are on different tables. The update is different. What optimization are you expecting to occur? Maybe the optimization is to read from the individual tables (using `UNION ALL`) rather than maintaining a `listing` table.

Comment: Alternate question, is there a performance problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I think that any modification which combines these triggers actions into one stored object is anti-optimization.

Comment: Is the trigger necessary?  It seems to be repeating what the `INSERT` did.  Please provide a sample `INSERT` statement.